# Xcode 4.3.2 10.7.3 app crash on launch

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios-simulator

I have an app which was running fine with Xcode 4.2. As soon as I upgraded to Xcode 4.3.2, the app crashes on the 5.1 simulator on launch.

0x44e5c3:  jmp    0x0044e63d               ; Poco::MutexImpl::lockImpl() + 317

Get a SIGABRT here.

```
Incident Identifier: CC84E826-5B79-4F66-9182-4C779CAF865B
CrashReporter Key:   98f4ee80ecae8f5500ce329f80122c35d6e7a4b7
Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
Process:         DataQuery [211]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/BF9857DC-CDD1-40D2-9660-              EB2187E28224/DataQuery.app/DataQuery
Identifier:      DataQuery
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-03-28 14:38:50.936 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B176)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x36b81848 __kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3156d2ae abort + 110
2   libc++abi.dylib               0x36a4af64 abort_message + 40
3   libc++abi.dylib               0x36a48346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
4   libobjc.A.dylib               0x36665368 _objc_terminate + 164
5   libc++abi.dylib               0x36a483be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
6   libc++abi.dylib               0x36a4844a std::terminate() + 14
7   libc++abi.dylib               0x36a49798 __cxa_throw + 116
8   DataQuery                     0x002dc45a Poco::MutexImpl::lockImpl() (Mutex_POSIX.h:82)
9   DataQuery                     0x003b67f6 Poco::FastMutex::lock() (Mutex.h:257)
10  DataQuery                     0x003b6820 Poco::ScopedLock<Poco::FastMutex>::ScopedLock(Poco::FastMutex&) (ScopedLock.h:59)
11  DataQuery                     0x003b49c6 Poco::Thread::uniqueId() (Thread.cpp:157)
12  DataQuery                     0x003b6228 Poco::Thread::Thread(std::string const&) (Thread.cpp:69)
13  DataQuery                     0x003116f8 com::pcbsys::foundation::fbase::fInternalTimer::fInternalTimer(com::pcbsys::foundation::fbase::fTimer*) (fTimer.cpp:77)
14  DataQuery                     0x00311276 com::pcbsys::foundation::fbase::fInternalTimer::fInternalTimer(com::pcbsys::foundation::fbase::fTimer*) (fTimer.cpp:67)
15  DataQuery                     0x003111e0 com::pcbsys::foundation::fbase::fTimer::fTimer() (fTimer.cpp:31)
16  DataQuery                     0x0031111e com::pcbsys::foundation::fbase::fTimer::fTimer() (fTimer.cpp:30)
17  DataQuery                     0x003127d8 __cxx_global_var_init + 144
18  DataQuery                     0x0031299c _GLOBAL__I_a + 0
19  dyld                          0x2fe8df64     ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 160
20  dyld                          0x2fe8dc6a ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 14
21  dyld                          0x2fe8b866 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 318
22  dyld                          0x2fe8c826 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 34
23  dyld                          0x2fe83a3a dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 266
24  dyld                          0x2fe87c16 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**) + 1430
25  dyld                          0x2fe822c8 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*) + 572
26  dyld                          0x2fe82058 _dyld_start + 48

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3fad4fbc
    r4: 0x2fdfe740    r5: 0x36665301      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fdfe74c
    r8: 0x000000e3    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x0000000d     r11: 0x0031299d
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fdfe738      lr: 0x3156d2b5      pc: 0x36b81848
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Comment: can you include some more information please? Copmuter Settings/OS etc..

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am running Xcode 4.3.2 on Lion 10.7.3

Comment: If you could post more from the stack crash for context that would also help. Also make sure that this is from the thread that crashed. Many times people will look at Thread 0 even though it was a different thread that crashed.

Comment: Added it...thank you Lord for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Not being as "expert" as you all seem to be, given the debug information provided, here are my 10 cents.

Context:
I was experiencing the same kind of problem.
I had a previous version of Xcode that was based on "Install Xcode" app from the app store, so i'm guessing 4.1 or 4.2.
Wanting to install 4.3.2, I found on the net a terminal command to uninstall Xcode completely which I chose to do, before installing 4.3.2 that I knew did not use the "Install Xcode" app.
Having uninstalled, the previous version, I then installed via App Store version 4.3.2.
And then, impossible to launch apps.
Even the default templates from the "new project" wizard, compiled fine, but whether on simulator or the devices themselves, Xcode would crash straight after trying to launch the app.

Solution:
What I did.
I uninstalled 4.3.2 => Trash.
Downloaded via the apple developper website 4.2.1 that I installed. (The download is actually the "Install Xcode" app).
Installed. Tested creating a default app. And it worked.
I then installed 4.3.2 via again a downloaded package from the developer website (not the app store).
Launched it ... and it asked if I wanted to uninstall the 4.2.1 version. Say yes.
Now it works.

Does this help ?